# Formatting date and time as in "Settings - Date and time"

Tags: android, datetime

There seems to be many ways to format date and time in Android - but none exactly the way I want ;-)

The methods I have been able to find involve the Locale (directly or indirectly) - but the correct way must be to use what the user has configured in "Settings - Date and time".

Using for example:

```
String res = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(java.text.DateFormat.SHORT, java.text.DateFormat.MEDIUM).format(date);
                Log.d("", res);
```

logs: 4/9/13 12:11:34 PM

and

```
res = android.text.format.DateUtils.formatDateTime(getActivity(), date.getTime(), android.text.format.DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME | android.text.format.DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE  | android.text.format.DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR);
                Log.d("", res);
```

logs: 12:11 April 9, 2013

BUT this is not how it is configured and when I look at a file's date and time it is written as: 09/04/2013 12:11

So how do I get the formatting strings (like "yyyy-MM-dd" and "HH:mm") configured in "Settings - Date and time" or alternatively, how do I get a Date formatted according to these rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use below code:

```
public static String convertDateToUserFormat(final Date inputDate) {
if (inputDate != null) {
    return getDateFormat().format(inputDate);
}

return null;
}

private static DateFormat getDateFormat() {
    final String format = Settings.System.getString(context.getContentResolver(),
            Settings.System.DATE_FORMAT);
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(format)) {
        return android.text.format.DateFormat
                .getDateFormat(context);
    }

    return new SimpleDateFormat(format);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Format dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
formattedDate = formatter.parse(yourDateString);
```

For more info on DateFormatter [check out the developer doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html)

Comment: As I understand it, this will return a Date - I wanted to go the other way.

Answer (score -1):

here is the example for date format

```
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
  Date date = new Date();

  System.out.println("format 1 " + sdf.format(date));

  sdf.applyPattern("E MMM dd yyyy");
  System.out.println("format 2 " + sdf.format(date));
```

u can follow this link for more info [enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)